# Random concatenation of data from different files into a single file using Ruby

Tags: ruby

For loading lines randomly from *one* file to another, we use this code:

```
# script.rb
X = 20  # no of lines needed
Y = 5   # no of words in each line
a = STDIN.readlines
X.times do
  b = []
  Y.times do
    b << a[rand(a.size)].chomp
  end
  puts b.join(",")
end
```

And execute it via:

```
ruby script.rb < input.txt > output.txt
```

I now have *two* files `Name.txt` (Which contains a list of names) and `Phone.txt` (Which contains a list of phone numbers).
I want to randomly take one name from `Name.txt` and one number from `Phone.txt` and combine them (Name and phone number separated by commas) into a new file.

How to do it using Ruby?

Output content should be of this form

```
name1,phoneno1
name2,phoneno2
```

and so on....

Comment: Where do `X` and `Y` come from?

Comment: X ->No of lines needed

Comment: Y->No of words in each line

Comment: So the code does not actually work? _"we use this code"_ sounds like you are already using it.

Comment: No,This code works for loading randomly loading data from a single file

Comment: Given we give replace X and Y with some value and give the file locations in code

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Your expected output doesn't look very random by the way.

Comment: if you are in linux try using /usr/share/dict/words as your input file it has big collection of words,you can see the words are loaded randomly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a file `Name.txt` with:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

and a file `Phone.txt` with:

```
123
456
789
```

Something like this would work:

```
# combine.rb
names = ARGF.file.readlines
ARGF.skip
phone_numbers = ARGF.file.readlines

5.times do
  puts "#{names.sample.chomp},#{phone_numbers.sample.chomp}"
end
```

This assumes that you pass the file names as arguments:

```
$ ruby combine.rb Name.txt Phone.txt
baz,456
baz,789
bar,123
foo,789
baz,123
```

Comment: I am new to ruby..So this may seem a very basic question...How to write this ouput into a new file? I tried File.write and used destination file as third argument...It is not working

Comment: @AkashAbi append `> output.txt` to the ruby command to redirect the script's output to the specified file, just like you did with your single-file approach.